# Set default directive for all input in app

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-input

I use `mat-form-field` with custom css in order to change the be look like `appearance="outline"` directive.

In `Angular Material v 7.2.1` `appearance="outline"` was added to the `mat-form-field` options.

How can I declare `appearance="outline"` as a default for each input fields in my app?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can try to inject mat-form-field default options in your `@NgModule`:

```
...
providers: [ 
   { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'outline' } } 
],
...
```

There was an issue with this https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12765, but I believe it has been solved.