# Trouble implementing the Notched Outline theme with Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I want to implement the Notched Outline Material theme with Angular Material. Material Design offers general install instructions (https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/notched-outline) but gives little information on using it with Angular itself (https://material.io/develop/web/docs/framework-integration). Has anyone successfully implemented MDC Web, such as Notched Outline, into a framework? What was your process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular Material [**Form field**](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) supports the [Material Notched Outline](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/text-field?type=outlined) theme. Set `appearance` to `outline`.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
  <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
  <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: Material Notched Outline]

See [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vvoyrgnqere?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.ts).

Comment: The Outline (the one you posted image of) seems to be broken on Safari. It might need some manual styling to get it right.

Comment: @Dino Are you seeing this issue? https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11577

Comment: @Dino Yes, it looks like you're seeing the same issue. At the bottom of the issue case someone else indicated that the bug still exists with Safari. I recommend adding a comment to the case and/or up-voting the note about the issue being unresolved.

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert is it possible to pass a token so that all MatFormFields default to "outline"?

Comment: @ebakunin Yes, you can configure default `MatFormField` options. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399778/1164465